# Adding additional parameter to django class based view

Tags: python, django

So first of all I admit I use CBV in django and I don't fully understand it.

I have a delete view implemented with CBV 
- I am trying to pass extra parameter uri 
    (this parameter is a current URL from where delete have been called, this  way after delete will get performed user will return to the same place from where he started.)

This is my url.py

```
url(r'^category/delete/(?P<pk>\d+)/(?P<uri>\S+)/$', item.views.CategoryDelete.as_view(),
    name='category_delete',),
```

and this is my view.py I am inheriting delete view functionality

```
class CategoryDelete(DeleteView):
    model = Category
    success_url = reverse_lazy(uri)

    def delete(self, uri, request, *args, **kwargs):
        try:
            return super(CategoryDelete, self).delete(
                request, *args, **kwargs
            )
        except models.ProtectedError as e:

            return HttpResponse(json.dumps(escape(e)))
```

Current code obviously gives me an error that uri is not defined.
So the question is how to transfer additional parameter into the View class if I want to use success_url ? Or there is a better  way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Trying to set `success_url` will not work, because it is processed when the module is loaded, not when the request is handled. Override `get_success_url` instead.

You can access positional and keyword arguments from the url from `self.args` and `self.kwargs` respectively.

```
def get_success_url(self):
    return reverse(self.kwargs['uri'])
```

Comment: thanks I thought I cant do it since since I have to create instance first.
When I try your code  I am getting this error:
Exception Type: NoReverseMatch
Exception Value: 
Reverse for 'uri' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{}' not found. 0 pattern(s) tried: []

Should I also do some changes in my url.py ?

Comment: If you are using `reverse`, the `uri` should be the name of the url pattern. If it's not a url pattern name, then you shouldn't be using `reverse` at all. Note that it's more common to include the next url as a GET parameter e.g. `?next=/home/`, rather than in the url itself.

Comment: I need whole URL since I am using filter so my users works only with data  they have filtered  ,and filter parameters are inside URL if I use reverse I will loose the filter values I assume

Comment: That's right, `reverse` would not return GET parameters.

Comment: Ok so I learned a great deal by investigating this topic and came to conclusion to eliminate CBV all together as unnecessary complexity. I will try to stick to FBV views only.